# API Error Code: 100

Tags: facebook, api

Just wanted to install my app to a fanpage, but got this message:

API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted

What does it mean? How can i fix this?

Greetz

Mark

Answer (score -1):

At https://developers.facebook.com/apps choose your app and click "Edit settings". In basic tab make sure your "Canvas URL" is set correctly.

I think that's the issue, if this doesn't fix it try looking for other "URL" attributes that might be off.